# Need help with an Integral-inequality over the sphere

Tags: real-analysis, inequality, hausdorff-measure

I need to prove the following: $$\int_{S^1}|x-y|^{-2}dS_y \leq c(1-|x|)^{-1}$$ where $x\in B_1(0)$ and $y \in S^1$.

I tried a fwe things that came to my mind, but I just cannot get there. For example, I cannot get anywhere with the triangle inequality. My ansatz was to seperate the problem in 2 cases:

Case 1: $ |x| \leq \frac{1}{2}$ 
Case 2: $\frac{1}{2} < |x| < 1$.

I tried the triangle inequality in case 1 for $\frac{1}{|x-y|^2}$, but then I get $\frac{1}{|x-y|^2} \geq \frac{1}{(|x|+|y|)^2} $ which is the wrong way. Am I missing something or does my ansatz not work?

Comment: Please include, in your question post, the attempts you claim to have made.  Maybe you got stuck in each of the "many things" you tried, but you might have been on the right track, but got stuck.  It might be due to a simple algebra error.

Comment: ok, maybe "many things" is not the correct term, I tried a few things that came in my mind and now i have no ideas anymore. Will edit that right now and include something I tried but failed.